# android textview will not update in spinner

Tags: android, textview

I Need help, i have this code. When i click the button, it will search for particular text in a array list then it will be populated into a spinner. At the same time the same spinner text line will be split into 4 textviews. The issue im facing is during the time the button is selected, the 4 textview is updated. But when i select the drop down spinner list and select one option, the textview is not updated. I added the toast to check on item selected. When i select the list the toast popup is showing the correct info. Only the text view is not updating.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.      

 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            titleString = spinner1.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            String[] items = titleString.split(";");
            for (String item : items)
            {
                Log.d("test",  item);
                contentData.add(item);
            }

            TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletextView);
            titleText.setText(contentData.get(0));

            TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questiontextView);
            questionText.setText(contentData.get(1));

            TextView causeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.causetextView);
            causeText.setText(contentData.get(2));

            TextView solutionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solutiontextView);
            solutionText.setText(contentData.get(3));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Selected : " + foundList.get(i) + " Level ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Button code

```
public void buttonClicked(View v){

    Log.d("test", "button clicked");

    strFind2 = mainSearchView.getText().toString();
    String strFind1 = "thr";


    for (String str : list) {


        if (str.contains(strFind2)) {

            foundList.add(str);

            Log.d("test", "contains search items");
            spinner1 =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.titleCategory1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, foundList);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);


        } else {
            Log.d("test", "don't contains search items");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your contentData list is empty before populating it?  I don't see it being created or cleared when entering the onItemSelected method and you are selecting the items by absolute positions.

Comment: Im still learning android coding. I dont have the code that you are eeffering to. Can provide me some sample? Thank you

Comment: In the toast you are using foundList.get(i) to display the data,  yet the text views get the data from spinner1.getItemAtPosition(i), is that providing the correct data?

Comment: Yes. Once I hit the search button. Text view will display the first spinner data. But when you select the second or other text view not updating. Get stuck with the first spinner data. The toast option is working correctly based on the spinner location touched. Fyi the toast I'm just using as to see if the spinner selection  is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue, your problem may be when you change the adapters backing array, you need to tell the adapter that the data has been changed.

Try this after pressing the button and changing the foundList

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i found the problem, its the for loop itself not working. I changed the line of code, i used `String[] split = titleString.split(";");`
                `String one = split[0];`
                `String two = split[1]; `                `TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletextView);
                titleText.setText(one);`

                `TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questiontextView);
                questionText.setText(two);`